# Is it correct to say ... "is that when"?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

Consider the following sentence:

> One disadvantage of exams is that students feel really irritated if
> they mess up one.

Is it correct if I change it to this one?

> One disadvantage of exams is **that when** students mess up one they
> feel really irritated.

Is it correct and natural to use "that when" in this sentence? I've read in a grammar book that using two relative pronouns is incorrect, but here they do not refer to the same thing.

Comment: "...mess **one** up" is correct. This is a separable phrasal verb, and if you use a pronoun object in a separable phrasal verb, the pronoun **must** go between the verb and the particle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct and natural to use "*that when*" in that sentence.

It's also true that you should not use two relative pronouns together. In this context, "that" is not a relative pronoun. Here, "that" is the head of a *noun clause*, while relative clauses with "that" are adjective clauses.

Some simpler examples to make the difference clear:

> I know [that you're leaving].

The portion in [brackets] is clearly a noun because it can be replaced with a pronoun:

> I know [something].

Also, there is no noun before it that it modifies, so it's not a relative pronoun.

However in this example:

> The bicycle [that I ride every day] is a Norco

the clause in [brackets] is an adjective that modifies the noun "bicycle". This means it's a relative clause with the relative pronoun "that" at its head.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/292380/one-disadvantage-of-exams-is-that-when-students-mess-up-one-they-feel-really-i :-)