# Is this correct? "One disadvantage of exams is that, when students mess one up, they feel really irritated"

Tags: commas

[In this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/292369/is-it-correct-to-say-is-that-when) the expression "that when" is really annoying to my eyes and I suggested to separate it with commas. One fellow member of the community said that using those commas is wrong.

Three questions:

1. Why is that the case?
2. Do phrases containing another explanatory phrase inside of them separated with commas exist in English? (Like the one in the title)
3. How are they called so I can Google them out, if they exist?

Comment: I agree with you that it is a good idea to separate the 'when' clause with commas.  I don't know why it is said to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the terms you are looking for are "subordinate clauses" and "restrictive clauses" (though I'm not an expert on the grammatical terms, but hopefully it will help you Google in the right direction). Here is [a good overview from Grammarly on it](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/subordinate-clause/).

Basically the rationale is that clauses that you wrap in commas are seen as "asides" — as in, these sections of the sentence are adding more information, but if you removed them the rest would still make sense on its own:

> We'll have 16 hours of sunlight as today, being June 21st, is the longest day of the year.

Here you can remove "being June 21st" and still have a complete 'thought':

> We'll have 16 hours of sunlight as today is the longest day of the year.

In your sentence, "when students mess one up" is a key part of the sentence as if you remove it, you get:

> One disadvantage of exams is that they feel really irritated.

In this shortened sentence, "they" now refers to "exams" rather than "students" and it doesn't make much sense! So here, "when students mess one up" is a restrictive clause (it's essential to the meaning) and wouldn't be wrapped in commas.

You could change your sentence slightly, e.g:

> One disadvantage of exams is that they can be really irritating.

Now the "they" is about the exams rather than the students. So the main thought makes sense on its own. If you add back in your aside it can become:

> One disadvantage of exams is that, when students mess one up, they can be really irritating.

While this is now grammatically "correct", it's arguably changed your thought quite a bit:

- It's changed the emphasis from the student being irritated to the exams being irritating
- It's calling exams irritating in general rather than when a student messes up
- It's arguable ambiguous whether the "they" refers to the students or the exams!

---

Other people will say though that you should ignore all that & just put commas in where you would naturally pause in a sentence if you were speaking it. Then it becomes largely a matter of style as to how you like to write, I guess.

I personally would phrase the sentence as:

> A disadvantage of exams is that students feel really irritated if they mess up in one of them.

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right that the meaning changes